# Cannot add add-ons to v3.20.0 of orange

Tags: python, orange

I just upgraded my version of orange and the add-ons I used before are no longer there.  I went to add them but I get a python error.  Is there a fix?

[image]

Comment: Try running Orange as an administrator and then installing add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

Because you installed Orange for all users, you need to run Orange as an administrator to install add-ons. Right click the icon and choose to run as administrator from the context menu.

If you had chosen to install Orange just for the current user, you would have been able to install add-ons without administrative privileges.